# Disable Office 365 account linking with other tools

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-account

I'm using a Microsoft Office Suite with Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and Outlook.
Each of these tools are not connected to any account.

As soon as I add an Office 365 mail account in my Outlook, it instantly connects this account to the whole Microsoft Office Suite (Word, Excel, PowerPoint).

I don't like this behavior, since the Office 365 account that I'm adding on Outlook is my work email.

I want to be able to read & answer my work mails from home with my home Office suite, without mixing up all my private & pro stuff.

How to solve this?

Comment: How are you using Office 365 (which is subscription based) without being logged into your Microsoft Account (which is connected to that subscription)?  I don't believe it's possible to link Office 365 to two difference Microsoft Accounts.  Once you have linked your Microsoft Account (with the appropriate Office 365 subscription) you should be able to also log into your work email.

Comment: At home I'm using Microsoft Office Standard, I don't have any Microsoft account linked to it, I've manually disconnected it after I bought the Office licence.
But now when I add my work email that is subscription based (E1), it connects my Suite to that account

Comment: The simplest solution is to link Office to a Microsoft Account that specifically does not have an Office 365 subscription, before you add your work account to Outlook, there isn't a simple solution to your problem since your work is clearly using subscription based model for Office.  I am going to guess, by `Microsoft Office Standard`, you actually mean `Microsoft Office 2019 Standard`

Comment: @Ramhound : yes in fact, that was the solution: connect a Microsoft account so that the second one comes after. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to read & answer my work mails from home with my home Office suite, without mixing up all my private & pro stuff.  How to solve this?

I am going to assume you are actually using a perpetual Office installation instead of Office 365 since that is a subscription and requires a Microsoft Account.  The simplest method to solve the problem you describe, is to first link to a Microsoft Account that does not have access to Office 365 subscription, before you add your work email to Outlook.

> I'm using a Microsoft Office Suite with Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and Outlook. Each of these tools are not connected to any account.
>
> As soon as I add an Office 365 mail account in my Outlook, it instantly connects this account to the whole Microsoft Office Suite (Word, Excel, PowerPoint).

Office 2016 and newer are designed to be linked to a Microsoft Account.  Many of the features that have been added most recently are designed around cloud storage.  I have personally experienced the situation where I have a perpetual Office 2019 installation, when I log-into to my Microsoft Account with an active Office 365 subscription, it will start to receive Office 365 only updates.

**However, linking to a Microsoft Account is not actually required to use any version of Office, your situation only exists due to the fact your work account is linked to a `E1 Office 365` subscription.**

Comment: Complete answer that solved many questions, thanks!