# Connect Office 2019 to OneDrive without a Microsoft account in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, onedrive, microsoft-account, microsoft-office-2019

I recently upgraded from Office 2013 to 2019. I used to be logged into OneDrive with Office to make use of versioning, and this sign in used to be isolated to just Office and its Upload Center (not even the built-in OneDrive app).

When trying to do so in 2019 (not 365, and registered with a key), however, it automatically adds my account as a Microsoft account in Windows, which did not happen with 2013. While I have read this appears to be the default behavior, is there any way of separating the two?

I would prefer to use a local account, and this question is asked with this in mind. I understand however that if this cannot be changed, I will be forced to go ahead with a Microsoft account.

Thank you everyone in advance.

Edit: To be specific, I'm running Windows 10 1909, and Office 1908.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Office 365 account linking with other tools](https://superuser.com/questions/1536099/disable-office-365-account-linking-with-other-tools)

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't. I do want my OneDrive account to be logged in throughout the Office suite, while that question does not. My main concern is not getting the OneDrive account added as a Microsoft account in Windows). I also don't have an Office 365 license on my account. Your point on how "[o]ffice 2016 and newer are designed to be linked to a Microsoft Account" is relevant to my case, but I would still like to see if there are any other possible solutions.

Comment: There are not; If you don't have an Office 365 subscription then Office 2019 can safely be logged into.  It's all or nothing with Office applications.

Comment: Thank you. Since this seems to currently be the only solution, I have marked music2myear's answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneDrive does not interact directly with Office. It integrates through OneDrive in the OS.

If you want OneDrive entries in Office you must be logged in to OneDrive in Windows.

Comment: Thank you. This appears to be the case, at least in Office 2019, based on your's and Ramhound's comments. Going to mark this as the answer, unless someone else has any additional info.